# How do I run multiple Scrapy spiders that each scrape a different URL?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a `spiders.py` in a Scrapy project with the following spiders...

```
class OneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "s1"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["url1.com",]
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="http://url1.com",
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self,response):
        ## Scrape stuff, put it in a dict
        yield dictOfScrapedStuff

class TwoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "s2"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["url2.com",]
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="http://url2.com",
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self,response):
        ## Scrape stuff, put it in a dict
        yield dictOfScrapedStuff
```

How do I run spiders `s1` and `s2`, and write their scraped results to `s1.json` and `s2.json`?

Comment: Maybe using  [Threads](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy doesn't support running multiple spiders as a single process, so you'd simply run two processes:

```
scrapy crawl s1 -o s1.json
scrapy crawl s2 -o s2.json
```

if you want to do it in the same terminal window you'd have to either:

- run 1st spider -> put it to background (ctrl+z) -> run 2nd spider
- use `nohup`, e.g.:

  ```
  nohup scrapy crawl s1 -o s1.json --logfile s1.log &
  ```
- use `screen` command.

  ```
  $ screen
  $ scrapy crawl s1 -o s1.json
  $ ctrl+a ctrL+d  # detach screen
  $ screen
  $ scrapy crawl s2 -o s2.json
  $ ctrl+a ctrL+d  # detach screen
  $ screen -r  # to reattach to one of your sessions to see how the spider is doing
  ```

Personally I prefer nohup or screen options as they are clean and do not mess up your terminal with logging and whatnot.