# How to run multiple spiders through individual pipelines?

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

Total noob just getting started with scrapy.

In my directory structure I have like this...

```
#FYI: running on Scrapy 2.4.1
WebScraper/
  Webscraper/
     spiders/
        spider.py    # (NOTE: contains spider1 and spider2 classes.)
     items.py
     middlewares.py
     pipelines.py    # (NOTE: contains spider1Pipeline and spider2Pipeline)
     settings.py     # (NOTE: I wrote here:
                     #ITEM_PIPELINES = {
                     #  'WebScraper.pipelines.spider1_pipelines': 300,
                     #  'WebScraper.pipelines.spider2_pipelines': 300,
                     #} 
  scrapy.cfg
```

And `spider2.py` resembles...

```
class OneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["url1.com",]
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="http://url1.com",
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self,response):
        ## Scrape stuff, put it in a dict
        yield dictOfScrapedStuff

class TwoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider2"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ["url2.com",]
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="http://url2.com",
            callback=self.parse
        )

    def parse(self,response):
        ## Scrape stuff, put it in a dict
        yield dictOfScrapedStuff
```

With `pipelines.py` looking like...

```
class spider1_pipelines(object): 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('spider1.csv', 'w', newline=''))
        self.csvwriter.writerow(['header1', 'header2'])
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        row = []
        row.append(item['header1'])
        row.append(item['header2'])
        self.csvwrite.writerow(row)
        
class spider2_pipelines(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('spider2.csv', 'w', newline=''))
        self.csvwriter.writerow(['header_a', 'header_b'])
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        row = []
        row.append(item['header_a']) #NOTE: this is not the same as header1
        row.append(item['header_b']) #NOTE: this is not the same as header2
        self.csvwrite.writerow(row)
```

I have a question about running spider1 and spider2 on different urls with one terminal command:

```
nohup scrapy crawl spider1 -o spider1_output.csv --logfile spider1.log & scrapy crawl spider2 -o spider2_output.csv --logfile spider2.log
```

*Note: this is an extension of a previous question specific to [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51181348/how-do-i-run-multiple-scrapy-spiders-that-each-scrape-a-different-url) (2018).*

**Desired** result: spider1.csv with data from spider1, spider2.csv with data from spider2.

**Current** result: spider1.csv with data from spider1, spider2.csv BREAKS but error log contains spider2 data, and that there was a `keyerror ['header1']`, even though the item for spider2 does not include `header1`, it only includes `header_a`.

Does anyone know how to run one spider after the other on different urls, and plug data fetched by spider1, spider2, etc. into pipelines *specific* to that spider, as in spider1 -> spider1Pipeline -> spider1.csv, spider2 -> spider2Pipelines -> spider2.csv.

Or perhaps this is a matter of specifying the `spider1_item` and `spider2_item` from items.py? I wonder if I can specify where to insert spider2's data that way.

Thank you!

Comment: I feel that I should make clear -- I do not intend to run spiders asynchronously, just one after the other. Hoping to do spider1->spider1_pipeline->spider1.csv, THEN spider2->spider2_pipeline->spider2.csv. If there's a more efficient way to code this, I'd also really appreciate that advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement this using [`custom_settings`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.4/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider) spider attribute to set settings individually per spider

```py
#spider2.py
class OneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider1"
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'WebScraper.pipelines.spider1_pipelines': 300}
...
class TwoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "spider2"
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'WebScraper.pipelines.spider2_pipelines': 300}
...
```